# Trying to find enabled or disabled Users in AD with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find AD Users that are enabled or disabled with Powershell Get-ADUser and I get an odd result. I know I have 30 disabled users in the Server Admin GUI, because every time I disable one I move it to a "Disabled OU". When I run

```
(Get-AdUser -filter * |Where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
```

I only get a value of 10

When I run

```
(Get-ADUser -filter * |Where {$_.enabled -ne "False"}).count
```

I get a value of 110

Something is not right as I know I have 30 disable users. When I run

```
Get-ADUser -filter *
```

Some users are not even using the field "Enabled". How can I get a list of Enabled or Disabled Users when some are not even using the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again from an Elevated PowerShell Command Prompt (Run as Administrator). See if the blanks go away when you run:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Enabled | FT Name, Enabled -Autosize
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have realized this when I tried to run `Disable-ADAccount` and I got an error, but when I ran `Disable-ADAccount` with an Elevated PowerShell Prompt it work. Thanks again